# WebGL not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl

Everytime I run a WebGL content, all I see is a black box and all of a sudden my browser crashes. I've search the forums and checked some documentation and still didn't find anything useful. I have Firefox 29.0 installed in my Windows 8. Does it have something to do with the operating system? I updated 7 from 8 last week, never had this problem before, help!

Comment: What GPU do you have? Why not latest Firefox version?

Comment: @frank I have AMD Radeon HD 6310. Isn't versions 29.x the latest Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problem with runnign WebGL on Chrome. It didn't crash though. My problem was that I have integrated Intel GPU and Nvidia GPU on my laptop. Chrome uses the integrated GPU by default. I had to force Chrome to start utulizing the Nvidia card. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for supported driver versions [here](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists).
2. By typing chrome://gpu/ in your Chrome browser check if WebGL is supported.

Comment: And when I start Google Chrome, WebGL runs perfectly. :] But that isn't part of my situation though, I still want to use FireFox while WebGL is working for that browser. Let me check up on the supported drivers list that you provided me.